# jquery DataTables: weird sort arrows

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

Working on a Django site with bootstrap. I'm getting these sort arrows for any jquery datatable. Any idea how to get the default ones shown [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html)?

[image: Weird arrows]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These arrows indicate that you're using [Bootstrap styling](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap). If you want to use [default styling](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/classes) use `class="display"` attribute for your table as shown below:

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
...
</table>
```

You also need to include CSS file for default style. You can generate your CSS/JS files using [download builder](https://www.datatables.net/download/index) and select **DataTables** option in **Styling** section.

Answer (score 0):

You'll generally only see those if you're using the default DataTables CSS styling.  There are bootstrap-datatables integration css js/css files that style the Datatables with Bootstrap styling.  Are you including those?  Are you including other CSS files that could be overriding it?  Using the **inspect element** tool in chrome or firefox can give you a clue as to what css is being used to style the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the sort arrows in **DataTables**.  My suspicion is it was an encoding problem - the way I solved it was to go into the CSS file that **DataTables** provided, find the triangle symbols, ▲ and ▼, that were put :before and :after the sort header, and changed them to `\2191` and `\2193` respectively.